# Glue AWS creating a data catalog table on boto3 python

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, boto3, aws-glue

I have been trying to create a table within our data catalog using the python API. Following the documentation posted [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_CreateTable.html) and [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_table) for the API. I can understand how that goes. Nevertheless, I need to undestand how to declare a field structure when I create the table because when I take a look on the Storage Definition for the table [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_Column.html) there is any explanation about how should I define this type of column for my table. In addition. I dont see the classification property for the table where is covered. Maybe on properties? I have used the boto3 [documentation](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glue.html#Glue.Client.create_table) for this sample

code:

```
import boto3


client = boto3.client(service_name='glue', region_name='us-east-1')


response = client.create_table(
        DatabaseName='dbname',
        TableInput={
        'Name': 'tbname',
        'Description': 'tb description',
        'Owner': 'I'm',
        'StorageDescriptor': {
            'Columns': [

                { 'Name': 'agents', 'Type': 'struct','Comment': 'from deserializer'  },
                { 'Name': 'conference_sid', 'Type': 'string','Comment': 'from deserializer'  },
                { 'Name': 'call_sid', 'Type': 'string','Comment': 'from deserializer'  }
            ] ,
        'Location': 's3://bucket/location/', 
        'InputFormat': 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat',
        'OutputFormat': 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat',
        'Compressed': False,
        'SerdeInfo': {  'SerializationLibrary': 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'}
        },
        'TableType' : "EXTERNAL_TABLE"} )
```

Answer (score 1):

Found this post because I ran into the same issue and eventually found the solution so you could do as type:

```
array<struct<id:string,timestamp:bigint,message:string>>
```

I found this "hint" while using the AWS Console and clicking on a data type of an existing table created via a Crawler. It hints:

```
An ARRAY of scalar type as a top - level column.
ARRAY <STRING>

An ARRAY with elements of complex type (STRUCT).
ARRAY < STRUCT <
  place: STRING,
  start_year: INT
>>

An ARRAY as a field (CHILDREN) within a STRUCT. (The STRUCT is inside another    ARRAY, because it is rare for a STRUCT to be a top-level column.)
ARRAY < STRUCT <
  spouse: STRING,
  children: ARRAY <STRING>
>>

A STRUCT as the element type of an ARRAY.
ARRAY < STRUCT <
  street: STRING,
  city: STRING,
  country: STRING
>>
```