# aws glue / pyspark - how to create Athena table programmatically using Glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I am running a script in AwsGlue which loads the data from s3, does some transformation and saves the results to S3. I am trying to add one more step to this routine. I want to create a new table in an existing database in Athena.

I cannot find any similar example in AWS documentation. The results are just written down to S3 in the examples I came across.
Is this possible in Glue?

There is some example of the code. How should it be modified to create the Athena table with the output results?

```
import sys
from awsglue.transforms import *
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.types import *


args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['JOB_NAME'])
sc = SparkContext()
glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session
job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args['JOB_NAME'], args)


datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "dataset", table_name = "table_1", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = datasource0, mappings = [("id", "long", "id", "long"), ("description", "string", "description", "string")], transformation_ctx = "applymapping1")
resolvechoice2 = ResolveChoice.apply(frame = applymapping1, choice = "make_struct", transformation_ctx = "resolvechoice2")
dropnullfields3 = DropNullFields.apply(frame = resolvechoice2, transformation_ctx = "dropnullfields3")
datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = dropnullfields3, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://..."}, format = "parquet", transformation_ctx = "datasink4")


*create Athena table with the output results*

job.commit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this. One is using the sdk to get a reference to the athena API and use it to execute a query with the create table statement, [as seen at this blog post](https://medium.com/@devopsglobaleli/introduction-17b4d0c592b6)

An alternative way which might be more interesting is using the Glue API to [create a crawler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-crawling.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-crawling-CreateCrawler) for your S3 bucket and then execute the crawler.

With the second approach your table is catalogued and you can use it not only from athena, [but also](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-athena.html) from EMR, or Redshift spectrum.

Comment: @ Javier Ramirez, creating a table using boto3 in a separate py script would be a work around option, however I was wondering if this operation would be possible directly on glue. There is a function create-table mentioned in the aws documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/webapi/API_CreateTable.html, but without example it is unclear to me if this can be used on glue in the script, and if it can be then how the function should look like

Comment: You can always do the table_creation in the same script, you don't need a different one. As you pointed out, you can also use the Glue API to create the table. You are pointing to the web API docs, which is accessible via boto3 (very similar to the solution I pointed) and you can see a full example at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52318838/glue-aws-creating-a-data-catalog-table-on-boto3-python. (more in next comment)

Comment: There is another version of the API directly on Glue (so no boto3 involved) documented at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-jobs-job.html#aws-glue-api-jobs-job-CreateJob. There is no example for this one, but since the parameters are the same as on the web one, you can probably use that as inspiration. Hope it helps